# I cloned a repository from a specific revision and I am ready to push, now what?

Tags: mercurial

I cloned a remote repository from a specific revision (prior to head). Since then, I have committed changes to my local repo and I'm ready to push these changesets to the remote repo.

I'm just wondering what happens to the remote repository since I didn't clone from head? Will my new changesets become the new head?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to push your changesets, you will probably get a message like this:

```
abort: push creates new remote head 8df8a97d46fd!
(you should pull and merge or use push -f to force)
```

The message says it all. You should pull and merge locally first (don't forget to commit your merge), and then you will be able to push. The use of `push -f` is not recommended unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: if this is my own repo (and private) and I don't care about the revisions that occurred post-clone, then I could force it no?

Comment: You can, but then you will have two heads in that repo. At some point you will need to either merge them or prune the branch that you don't use (some tips about pruning: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PruningDeadBranches).